# Struts 2 passing data from JSP to action class

Tags: java, jsp, struts2, ognl

I'm trying to understand somebody's else Struts 2 code and I'm stuck with a data passing problem.

I know that on a JSP page, if you use a `<s:textfield name="something" ... />` tag, than struts2 will try to call `setSomething(...)` automatically in the action class.

I'm now seeing this type of code:

```
<s:textfield name="item.name" ... />
```

and I'm wondering, how does this `.` (dot) work? I have a method called `setItem()` in my action class, and the object that is being set in that method has a `setName()` method, but apparently this doesn't work. What does the dot mean between item and name and how do I use it correctly to instantiate the item *and* set it's name?

PS: The item object that is being set in `setItem()` in my action class has an empty `args` constructor.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is solved. The getItem() actually contained the following code:

```
public Item getItem()
{
    System.out.println("Trying to get item: " + item.toString());
    return item;
}
```

And this gave a nullpointer exception because item was null. Only, this nullpointerexception was NOT THROWN by the struts framework! The code just continued (and failed of course...). When I removed the sysout statement, the code worked.

Answer (score 3):

In OGNL `.` is the *dot notation*.

`item.name` means `getItem().setName();`

`item.subitem.name` means `getItem().getSubitem.setName();`

One problem could be the missing empty args constructor, [as described here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19562738/1654265), but you are saying it's not your case; then I bet on the "missing getter for `Item`". If it's not, please post more relevant code.

Answer (score 1):

Make sure there is public method for `getItem().setName()`

Maybe the methods are not available or not public or a typo, for example getitem() instead of getItem().

Your action should have `setItem(Item item)`

Answer (score 1):

Struts2 treated value in the `name` attribute `"item.name"` like OGNL expression. But it doesn't substitute the result of evaluation to the `name` attribute but to the `value` attribute if it didn't set. Then if you submit the form the parameter from the `name` attribute is created and sent via HTTP request. Struts2 used `params` interceptor to parse parameter names. It treated such names like OGNL expression and call appropriate methods `get` and `set` while accessing objects and setting values. Dot in OGNL expression stands for property resolver. In your case you should have `getItem()` method to set the value and this item should return not `null` value. `setItem()` is not used there. May be you ask why it's not used, but it would probably another question.