# Struts 2 accessing class properties with JQuery Grid

Tags: jquery, jsp, struts2, jqgrid, ognl

I'm trying to learn about the `struts2-jQuery-plugin`, more specifically the `struts2-jQuery-grid-plugin`. For now I've replicated the tutorial provided by the developers [HERE.](https://code.google.com/p/struts2-jquery/wiki/GridTag) I've been successful in displaying inside the grid such a simple class as `Customer` (in their example), which I can reference just fine from the mentioned grid inside the `JSP` and works perfectly fine:

```
 <sjg:grid
    id="gridtable"
    caption="Customer Examples"
    dataType="json"
    href="%{remoteurl}"
    pager="true"
    gridModel="gridModel"
    rowList="10,15,20"
    rowNum="15"
    rownumbers="true">

    <sjg:gridColumn name="id" index="id" title="ID" formatter="integer" sortable="false"/>
    <sjg:gridColumn name="name" index="name" title="Name" sortable="true"/>
    <sjg:gridColumn name="country" index="country" title="Country" sortable="false"/>
    <sjg:gridColumn name="city" index="city" title="City" sortable="false"/>
    <sjg:gridColumn name="creditLimit" index="creditLimit" title="Credit Limit" formatter="currency" sortable="false"/>
</sjg:grid>
```

But things start to complicate whenever I try to use not this simple `Customer` class but another from my own, for example let's say class `Reservation` (I'm posting examples as I dont want to complicate the question with my own project code):

```
public class Reservation {

 private Customer customer;
 private Car vehicle;

 public setCustomer(Customer customer){
 this.customer = customer;
 }
 public setCar(Car vehicle){
 this.vehicle = vehicle;
 }

}
```

So **how do I access now the properties/fields inside Customer, which is also inside Reservation?** Coming from Struts2 and using `<s:property />` tags before using this jQuery plugin, I've been trying to do so like this, as the grid inside the `JSP` receives a JSON containing all the data:

```
<sjg:gridColumn name="customer.city" index="city" title="City" sortable="false"/>
```

But it's not working as my grid columns show empty..

Also **is it possible to apply any OGNL expresion to the fields displayed?** Let's say I want to uppercase the content of a column, before I started using jQuery Grid, I could manage this by applying `.toUpperCase()` to the property I displayed, but now using this plugin I'm a bit lost.

**UPDATE**

I've been able to confirm that it's possible to access the "complex" object using the notation I displayed (tested with other "complex" class). So I think my problem lays inside the JSON generation of my specific class (the one I didn't write down so I don't make the question more complex)... I'll try to take a look inside the generated JSON passed to the Grid and let you know what happens there.

**SOLVED:** Found a nullpointer inside the JSON generation,so I fixed it. The problem layed there. Accepted answer goes to @Andrea as he pointed out how to access the inner objects of an object, which was my initial question (although I was doing it properly but failed due to the nullpointer issue).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> how do I access now the properties/fields inside Customer, which is also inside Reservation?

Exactly the way you are doing. If it doesn't work, you are doing something wrong.

Try changing the `index` to the main object, btw:

```
<sjg:gridColumn name="customer.city" index="customer" title="City" sortable="false"/>
```

And ensure you have a `List<Reservation>`, and that all your objects (Reservation, Customer, Car, etc...) [have a no-args constructor](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19562738/1654265) (either implicit or declared), and that every getter and setter is correctly declared.

Comment: Thanks for your response @Andrea . 

First I ensured I had a List<Reservation> inside my gridModel when the action executes, and all getters and setters are placed.  
I also tried changing the index but it didn't work either. Also checked I havn't forgotten the empty constructor, nor any getters or setters... It's weird because Im testing within the same action with the two cases, first using just the "simple" class and when I see it shows correctly all data, I try to switch to the "complex" class but it shows nothing.. :(

Comment: Maybe there's some error while generating the JSON for the grid and I'm not noticing it, and that would explain why it doesn't show anything. In the past I had some issues with parsing null values with JSON (`Vehicle`in `Reservation`could be null).

Comment: `a List<Reservation> inside my gridModel` :| the list must be THE model itself, not being inside it

Comment: XD yes, sorry for my rusty english, inside my action I've got a `List<Reservation> gridModel` :P. Apologies again :)

Comment: could you tell me something about my tiny second question? I wondered if it is possible to apply OGNL to any of the data rows inside the grid, for example for uppercasing a field, or do I have to manipulate data earlier inside the action?.

Comment: No, you can't use OGNL on JSON... you can do it through a formatter: http://stackoverflow.com/a/22408093/1654265 (maybe read my question too, to understand the answer). Uppercase, show hide, enabled disabled... handle them with formatters, both out-of-the-box (ready to use) or, like in my case, custom created

Comment: Okay many thanks, I'll take a look.. but I feel like I won't be able to archieve the same things I could do with OGNL now using JQuery Grid :(

Comment: If my (linked) answer is not enough, feel free to ask a new question about this formatting problems.

Comment: P.S: also consider upvoting if you find something useful, thanks :)